# String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The issue I am having is I am receiving the following error, I went into MySql and ran:

```
ALTER TABLE block_content__field_views_reference_book 
MODIFY COLUMN field_views_reference_book_target_id varchar(500);
```

To change it up from varchar(5) but still getting the error below, any suggestions? What am I missing?:

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'field_views_reference_book_target_id' at row 1: INSERT INTO {block_content_r__e6f3906112} (entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, langcode, field_views_reference_book_target_id, field_views_reference_book_display_id, field_views_reference_book_data) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 46 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 339 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => hp_book [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => en [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => book [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => block_1 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => a:5:{s:6:"offset";N;s:5:"pager";N;s:5:"limit";N;s:5:"title";N;s:8:"argument";N;} ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 846 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

Results of SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `block_content__field_views_reference_book` (
  `bundle` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to',
  `langcode` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language code for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_views_reference_book_target_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `field_views_reference_book_display_id` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The ID of the display.',
  `field_views_reference_book_data` longtext DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Serialized data.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`langcode`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `field_views_reference_book_display_id` (`field_views_reference_book_display_id`),
  KEY `field_views_reference_book_target_id` (`field_views_reference_book_target_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Data storage for block_content field field_views_reference…' |
```

Comment: Please provide the table structure, after it has changed. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE block_content__field_views_reference_book;` for it

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Edited and added the response to the original question.

Comment: as you can see the column `field_views_reference_book_target_id` is  varchar(250) NOT NULL. What data you try to insert into this column?

Comment: I looked again on error message and see the error is about another table: `{block_content_r__e6f3906112}` Can you check this table structure too? From error message also can see that value is  `[:db_insert_placeholder_5] => book`, so perhaps the column type smaller then `varchar(4)`

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev ah found it! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

What version?  What `CHARACTER SET`?  And other issues.  Before version 5.5, there was `CHARACTER SET utf8`, which needs up to 3 bytes per character, but not `utf8mb4`, which needs up to 4.  With 5.7 (10.2?), the problem was 'solved'.  Meanwhile, an index had been limited to 767 bytes; not it is 3072.

Your index on a `VARCHAR(500)` needs 1500 or 2000 bytes.

Here is my list of 5 things that could be done:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

You need to choose among them based on which flaw you can live with.

Answer (score 1):

**this is what i tried and it works, for drupal 8**

```
  ALTER TABLE node_field_data MODIFY title VARCHAR(500);
 ALTER TABLE node_field_revision MODIFY title VARCHAR(500);
```